# Using python in FreeRADIUS

Tags: python, freeradius

[There seems to be documentation lacking](http://wiki.freeradius.org/modules/Rlm_python) on how to use the python module in FreeRADIUS.

I want to use python to interpret a MAC address (in %{Calling-Station-ID}) and return an IP address.

In my `sites-enabled/default` I have:

```
accounting {
...
python
update request {
Framed-IP-Address := "%{python:/path/python-script -m %{Calling-Station-ID}}"
}
```

This returns:

```
WARNING: Unknown module "python" in string expansion "%"
```

What is the proper way to create a python module for FreeRADIUS?

**EDIT:**

I found out that I can do:

```
Framed-IP-Address := `/usr/bin/python /path/python-script -m "%{Calling-Station-Id}"`
```

This returns the following:

```
+- entering group accounting {...}
    expand: "%{Calling-Station-Id}" -> "XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX"
Exec-Program output: None 
Exec-Program-Wait: plaintext: None 
Exec-Program: returned: 0
ERROR: Failed parsing value "None" for attribute Framed-IP-Address: Failed to find IP    address for None
++[reply] returns fail
```

Comment: Do you actually have the Python support for FreeRADIUS installed?

Comment: It is installed with the freeradius package on Debian distros. About to update this with the solution I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is without quotes:

```
Framed-IP-Address := `/usr/bin/python /path/python-script -m %{Calling-Station-Id}`
```

In my examples above, I had quotes around `%{Calling-Station-Id}`.